# What is "a'rovin"?

Tags: meaning

I have been listening sea chanties and I found one named *The Maiden from Amsterdam*, but in the lyrics it says

> A rovin', a rovin'
>   Since rovin's been my ru-i-in,
>   I'll go no more a roving,
>   With you fair maid!

So the question, is what is *a roving* ?

Comment: http://www.jsward.com/shanty/amsterdam/hugill.html

Comment: **roving** *(adj)*: going to many different places. The *a* is just a lyrical addition.

Comment: "Roving" means "roaming"... wandering about.

Comment: I wonder if the shanty might be younger than, and alluding to, Byron's "So we'll go no more a-roving."

Answer (score 3):

*Rovin*' is short for *[roving](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roving)*.

> Adjective:
>
> going to many different places
>
> M-W

*A rovin'* employs an artistic device in music to fill the meter. Without the stylization:

> Oh Roving, Oh Roving
>
> Since Roving's been my ruin,
>
> I'll go no more roving,
>
> With you fair maid!

He'll not be rovin' with this "fair maiden" anymore!

Comment: Or maybe, he is married to another, and he's done a rovin' with this not-so-fine woman?

Comment: [And so it is!](http://www.jsward.com/shanty/amsterdam/hugill.html) @GoodA.M.!

Answer (score 1):

Oxford English Dictionary.

**Roving *adj***

> 1. Of speech, thought, etc.: moving from one thing to another; treating of many subjects unsystematically; rambling, unstructured;
>      (also) constantly active; rest
> 2. Of a manner of doing something, a person's life, etc.: characterized by roving (roving n.1 2) or an inclination to rove; esp.
>      (of life, a period of time, etc.) spent roving. Cf. roving n.1
>
> 3.a. Of a person's eyes, gaze, etc.: moving in changing directions, esp. in appraising or searching for something, spec. with allusion to
>   a tendency to flirt or be constantly looking for new potential sexual
>   or romantic partners, esp. when one is already in a relationship
>   (chiefly in roving eye). Cf. rover n.2 2b.
>
> b. Of a person or a person's mind: inclined towards sexual promiscuity
>   or adultery; adulterous; promiscuous.
>
> 4. a. Esp. of a person or animal: that travels from place to place without fixed route or destination; wandering, roaming; nomadic;
>      (also) marauding.
>
>    b. Of a person in relation to his or her job: required to travel to
>      various locations; peripatetic. Freq. in roving reporter.
>
> c. Sport. Having the freedom or propensity to move about the field of
>   play at will rather than remain in a set position. Cf. roving
>   commission n. 3
>
> 5. Made or held on the basis of incomplete information; conjectural. Cf. rove v.2 3a. Obs.

**There are multiple examples of each use starting from circa 1560.**

Comment: I’m going to have *The Gypsy Rover* stuck in my head all night now. :)

Comment: @tchrist Interesting that the OED describes it as an adjective. It presumably isn't regarded as a verb, because it is not used in any other form. Though I think I have heard things like *would you rove around and see who's there...*.